# Does PyCharm use Mypy?

Tags: python, pycharm, mypy

Does PyCharm use Mypy or did JetBrains implement [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) separately?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[It appears that they went with their own implementation.](https://github.com/python/mypy#ide-linter-integrations-and-pre-commit)

Ultimately I would conjecture whether or not they use another open source library instead matters little; so long as [they maintain their support for it](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html), their choice of implementation is inconsequential.

Comment: The [Mypy README](https://github.com/python/mypy) mentions that "PyCharm integrates its own implementation of PEP 484" as well.

Comment: Actually, it matters: mypy fully supports [attrs](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs), but PyCharm is actually complaining about parameters with a `converter`, which mypy is not, so unless JetBrains really commits to it (which is a duplicated effort imho), this has consequences

Comment: @Nicola:  You misunderstand.  So long as PyCharm adheres to PEP 484, whether they use MyPy or their own homebrew is irrelevant, since they have a PEP to adhere to.

Comment: I got that, but since there are different "levels" (or qualities) of adherence, using a well used, well maintained and well integrated in python echodystem option would for sure matter for the user experience