# Typing: list of A and subclass of A

Tags: python

```
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

ListOfA = List[A]

list_of_a : ListOfA = [A(), A()]

for e in [B()] + list_of_a:
    pass
```

I get:

```
Expected type 'List[B]' (matched generic type 'List[_T]'), got 'List[A]' instead
```

I would like that `e` for each element in the list is considered as an instance of `A`, since `B` is a subclass of `A`. What is the correct way to do this in python?

The code works, but Pycharm gives a warning about wrong typing.

Comment: Where do you get this error from? The code works fine for me.

Comment: Edited, the warning comes from Pycharm typing check. Code works, but I want to do it the right way with the correct types.

Comment: changing to `list_of_a + [B()]` will remove the warning

Comment: it works, but why is that? It doesn't seems quite right since the elements in the list are not in the order intended.

Comment: The type checker isn't that smart. It doesn't look at an expression `x + y` and try to determine if there's a general type that covers both `x` and `y`; it simply looks at the static type of `x` (since it's `x.__add__` that provides the type hint).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known pitfall with type consistency checking, and it has to do with the [variance of generic types](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#variance-of-generic-types). The problem is that `List` is considered to be an invariant generic type, meaning that `List[B]` is not automatically considered to be a subtype of `List[A]` (the reason being that you cannot add an instance of `A` to a `List[B]`, so they are not really compatible types). In [Invariance vs covariance](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#invariance-vs-covariance) there is an example of this problem and different ways to work around it. In your case, you can for example just add an annotation for the additional list:

```py
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

ListOfA = List[A]

list_of_a : ListOfA = [A(), A()]

list_of_b : ListOfA = [B()]
for e in list_of_b + list_of_a:
    pass
```

EDIT: I was assuming PyCharm was using Mypy, but apparently [that is not the case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50497956). However, the same reasoning applies.

Comment: A little extra reading material: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2984

Comment: Does PyCharm actually use `mypy`, or does it do its own type checking? (Granted, it issue of list invariance would be the same either way, but talking about `mypy` isn't necessarily relevant.)

Comment: @chepner Huh, good point, I assumed so, but [apparently not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50497956).